# Using SVG Files as Labels in QGIS?

Tags: qgis

I have trail data in shapefiles.  Each trail record includes a "difficulty" field, and I would like to use this field to display a standard ski slope difficulty icon next to each trail.  I have these icons as SVG files.

This seems like a labeling matter to me.  I have, for example, use trail length fields to display the length next to the trail.  And of course I have the trail name displayed as well.  I would like to display difficulty, not as the numerical values of "1", "2", "3", or "4", but as a different SVG icon based on whether the trail's difficulty field is set to 1, 2, 3, or 4.

But I can't find a way to do this in QGIS 2.18, in which "labeling" seems focused on text data and it's formatting.

Comment: another option would be to use the svg as the label background

Answer (score 13):

I'd recommend working with symbology instead of labeling, specifically using a **marker line**. The marker (in your case the trail SVG) can be placed at the center of the line as shown here:

[image]

[image]

(The screenshots are from an older version of QGIS but they show the general settings you'd be looking for.)